# Breadth First Search in Python with Queue

Tags: python, queue, binary-tree, breadth-first-search

can anyone help me with an bfs code in python? It's printing just self value, not the entire tree.

```
from queue import *

class BinaryTree:
   def __init__(self,info,left,right):
    self.info  = info
    self.left  = left
    self.right = right

def bfs(self): 
    queue = Queue()
    queue.put(self)

    while not queue.empty():
        self = queue.get()
        print(self.info)

        if self.left:
            queue.put(self.left)

        if self.right:
            queue.put(self.right)
        return

nine = BinaryTree("9",None,None)
eleven = BinaryTree("11",None,None)
two = BinaryTree("2",eleven,nine)
one   = BinaryTree("1",None,None)
seven = BinaryTree("7",one,None)
five = BinaryTree("5",seven,two)
three = BinaryTree("3",None,None)
six = BinaryTree("6",None,None) 
four = BinaryTree("4",None,six)
eight = BinaryTree("8",four,three)
ten = BinaryTree("10",eight,five)

ten.bfs()
```

The answer to me is just "10", not the entire tree. I can't find the error.

Comment: you are `returning` in the while loop and it is exiting after the first node, just shift+tab it out

Comment: Or just delete it

Comment: Do you really need `Queue` this is generally used for synchronizing across threads, a simple `list` or `collections.deque` would do.

Comment: omg, u are correct, thanks guys.

Answer (score 5):

Along with the `return` statement, there are some wrong indentations too.

```
from queue import *

class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self,info,left,right):
        self.info  = info
        self.left  = left
        self.right = right 

    def bfs(self): 
        queue = Queue()
        queue.put(self)

        while not queue.empty():
            self = queue.get()
            print(self.info)

            if self.left:
                queue.put(self.left)

            if self.right:
                queue.put(self.right)

nine = BinaryTree("9",None,None)
eleven = BinaryTree("11",None,None)
two = BinaryTree("2",eleven,nine)
one   = BinaryTree("1",None,None)
seven = BinaryTree("7",one,None)
five = BinaryTree("5",seven,two)
three = BinaryTree("3",None,None)
six = BinaryTree("6",None,None) 
four = BinaryTree("4",None,six)
eight = BinaryTree("8",four,three)
ten = BinaryTree("10",eight,five)

ten.bfs()
```

**Input Graph:**

[image: input graph]

**Output:**

```
10
8
5
4
3
7
2
6
1
11
9
```

**Reference:**
https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get

Comment: Thank you so much Arsho.